# Rails 2.3.5 - ".find" function doesn't work with (:condition =>"date") option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, date, conditional-statements

What I want to do is finding specific records that have been used over the last 60 days.

I am using Oracle (9i),
Rails v: 2.3.5,
Ruby v: 1.8.7

My Code to define the date interval is:

```
date =(((Time.now - 60.days).strftime("%d-%b-%y"))...(Time.now.strftime("%d-%b-%y")))
```

and here is how I use it:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:start_date] = date
conditions[:account_no] = account_number

results = MyModel.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
```

to see what is selected, I basicly do:

```
results.each {|r|
  if (!(r.column_name.nil?))
     #do something here
  end
}
```

Result:
Code is working but the "results" is empty

However, when I copy and paste the query that generated by the "MyModel.find..." to sqlDeveloper, I can definitly see what I want.

What should be the reason that I can't get the same results with SQL Developer, Although I use the same query that is generated by above code

Comment: take out the `strftime`s, and pass raw Time values. Rails is ridiculously good at converting whatever into the correct database formats.

Comment: I don't believe it's worked, thank you.. but I still couldn't get the idea behind how generated query is working but the code is not..
Thanks again

Comment: Why are you passing abbreviated Month `%b`? is this how the data is stored? Usually Rails stores dates as `%Y-%m-%d` you are passing a Range of Strings not dates.

Comment: Database is storing the date as (for ex:"11-Oct-13") that is why I used strftime. Problem is solved now, I am only angry because the query generated by the rails was working so I never think of deleting the strftime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work given start_date is a Date

```
date =((DateTime.now - 60)...(DateTime.now))
conditions = {}
conditions[:start_date] = date
conditions[:account_no] = account_number

results = MyModel.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
```

This will cause date to be a range of Dates as opposed to a range of strings.

Right now if you run date.to_a it returns an empty array because it is an improper range.

If you run the above with date.to_a it will return an array of dates back 60 days exclusive of today's date. Which will create a proper `IN` statement in the generated SQL